# Can not receive TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED event on android 7.0

Tags: android, notifications, accessibilityservice

I wrote a Accessibility service, and start the service by manual。the app works fine on android 6.0. Today, I update my device to 7.0(Nougat),the app is not working,it can not receive the TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED event.

what should I do?

Service:

```
       <service
        android:name=".Service.MyAccessibilityService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <!--
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            -->
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/service_permistions" />
    </service>
```

service_permistions:

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:description="@string/accessibility_des"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
android:notificationTimeout="30"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:packageNames="com.xx.cc"
/>
```